# Is there any way to create index in Pig Script?

Tags: hadoop, indexing, hbase, apache-pig

I have a data file which has no id number ( index). Can one create index of each entry using UDF or any inbuilt function in pig?. For example:

```
data = load 'myfile.txt' using PigStorge(',') AS ( speed:float, location:charrarray);
A = foreach data generate index as (Id:int), speed, location;
```

I am having problem loading data from pig to Hbase because hbase reads speed as row-key value and there are many duplicate data (speed) in my file. I want to set index as row-key value and store in Hbase table. Do you have any suggestion for this?. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, adding an increasing count like an ID is really hard to do in distributed computing. The problem is each split needs to know how many numbers were before it in order to keep counting. So, I don't suggest that approach.

You can write a UDF that generates a Java UUID or you can use [RANDOM](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#random) to just generate a random number. For example:

```
data = load 'myfile.txt' using PigStorge(',') AS ( speed:float, location:charrarray);
A = foreach data generate RANDOM() as id, speed, location;
```

---

Some unsolicited advice: you need to think about why you are using HBase for a second. The whole point of using a key-value store is so that you can look up things by keys. If you are just jamming it into HBase with an arbitrary ID, how are you going to look it up? If you are just planning on doing full table scans, you should probably just be using HDFS.

What kinds of questions are you going to ask of your data? If you are doing by location, you could make your location be part of the key and have the event be in the row.

Comment: I assure you that you are just using it wrong or don't understand how the data model works. It is neither garbage or incomplete. You should read more about it to figure out what it can do for you, but what you need to do in order for it to work correctly. For example, in 2010, Facebook was using HBase to store 135 billion messages a month. I'm sure it can handle your sensor data. http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/11/16/facebooks-new-real-time-messaging-system-hbase-to-store-135.html

Answer (score 2):

Pig 0.14 version supports built-in function `UniqueID`. It will return unique id string for each record in the form of "taskindex-sequence".

```
A = foreach data generate UniqueID() as id, speed, location;
```

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#uniqueid

Comment: I had no idea this was a thing. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score -1):

This was simply solved by using the following python UDF:

```
import random 
from datetime import datetime as dt

def currTime():
    x =dt.now()
    return x.microsecond+  int(random.random()*100)+x.second*1000000
```

In every steps it generates the unique number and i used this number as an  index. Still there is a chance to be same index in different entries but it is too small, which could be less than(0.01%) and depends on the processing time of computer for each unit step.

Comment: You are absolutely going to get duplicate IDs using this. `x.microsecond` has 1000 values, `x.second` has 60 values, and `int(random.random()*100)` has 100 values = 6m combinations. By the birthday problem you will have a 99% chance of a duplicate ID after only 7434 ID generations.